# How to install Cudnn from command line

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia, cudnn

Cudnn: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

I login and go jump through all the hoops that NVIDIA wants you to do; however, when it comes time to download the file I can't seem to figure out how to do it via wget and the command line.

I was hoping someone has done this. I've copy and pasted the link that they want to click and used this in wget copy-and-pasted-url. But I just get back an html file.

Answer (score 23):

The following trick works with Firefox:

1. Download the file with your regular machine
2. Go to the downloads list in firefox, right click on the file and click "Copy original download URL"

[image]

3. Go to your pure-terminal machine, and type:

   wget PASTE-YOUR-LINK-FROM-FIREFOX

As @deltheil mentionned, by doing this the link contains a temporary download token, letting you download the file from another machine then the one it was requested from

## EDIT

The downloaded filename is `libcudnn***.deb?<some download token>`. You will need to rename it by stripping the `?` and everything after it:

```
mv libcudnn***.deb?xxx libcudnn***.deb
```

Comment: Or, download and rename altogether: `wget download_link -O desired_name`.

Answer (score 10):

```
CUDNN_TAR_FILE="cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0.tgz"
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v6.0/${CUDNN_TAR_FILE}
tar -xzvf ${CUDNN_TAR_FILE}
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Comment: The URL might look like https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v8.7.0/local_installers/11.8/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.7.0.84_cuda11-archive.tar.xz nowadays

Answer (score 6):

The download link that you get right after the accept terms section is authenticated (the `GET` request gives you a `HTTP 302 Moved Temporarily`).

If you *really* want to grab the link from the command line: open your browser, use the developers tools and look at the `Location` field after the redirection: you can use this link directly with `wget` as it contains a short-lived authorization token.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following:

```
curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v2/cudnn-6.5-linux-x64-v2.tgz
```

This will download CUDNN 6.5

Answer (score 1):

The location for the latest one is in the NVIDIA latest Docker file, currently at:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/tree/master/centos-7/cuda/7.5/runtime/cudnn5

Comment: Dead link as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these answers and none worked unfortunately.

Though a simple workaround is: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends <cuDNN Package>`

For example, in my case it is:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcudnn8
```

And it works!

Comment: I tried the following:
`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcudnn8-8.1.1.33-1.cuda11.2.x86_64` and got the error:
` GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC`

Answer (score 0):

Click on the version of cudnn you want to install from [Index of /compute/redist/cudnn/](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/) and follow it.
When you reach the page shown in the image below, right-click to get the url for wget.

[image]

You just wget cudnn from that link and install it. The commands below assume you are using Ubuntu.

```bash
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v8.8.0/local_installers/11.8/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.8.0.121_1.0-1_arm64.deb
sudo apt install cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.8.0.121_1.0-1_arm64.deb
```